With helm is there a way to tell if you are running a dry run or not?
I don't want to fail a dryrun just because a value doesn't exist that I expect to be there.
Ideally the builtin Release object would have the context but unfornately it does not.
It'd be nice if something like this would work.
{{- if .Release.IsDryrun and /* other conditions/ }}
 //print message
 {{ else}}
 //fail hard and fast
{{- end }}


Build-in Objects in the Helm documentation shows what's in .Release.  If it's not in that page, and you're not manually passing it in .Values, there's not another way to get that bit of information.

I was hoping to avoid having to do that. Having to pass pass in value to determine if you are running a dryrun or not is tedious.

There's the side question of why exactly it matters.  I'd be surprised if helm template or helm install --dry-run produced YAML that was significantly different from what was going to be installed in the cluster given the same values.

My use case failing an installation|upgrade if certain conditions failed. For example I wanted it to fail if a installation was deployed to a production vs development cluster by reading a ConfigMap that has metadata for the cluster. I only wanted it to spit out an error message if were a dry-run. Yes I can get similar behaviour by passing in a variable to control this functionality but that is yet one more thing to have to remember when testing/installing my chart.
